# UICollectionViewFlowLayout animation between datasets

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that when a cell is pressed, there will be a new set of data and will animate the flow layout.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        [tempArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    items = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

   CollapseLayout *currentLayout = (CollapseLayout *)_collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
currentLayout.collapse = YES;
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.collectionView.numberOfSections)]];
} completion:nil];
}
```

It is using a Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout that performs an animation when reloading the data. 
My CustomFlowLayout Class is here

```
#import "CollapseLayout.h"

@implementation CollapseLayout
- (void)prepareLayout {
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(200, 100);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 30;
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
}

- (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray* allAttributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    if(_collapse)
    {
         for(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in allAttributesInRect)
         {
             attribute.frame = CGRectMake(attribute.frame.origin.x - self.collectionView.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.origin.y, attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);
         }
    }
    return allAttributesInRect;
}
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* allAttributesInRect = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(_collapse)
    {
         allAttributesInRect.frame = CGRectMake(allAttributesInRect.frame.origin.x - self.collectionView.frame.size.width, allAttributesInRect.frame.origin.y, allAttributesInRect.frame.size.width, allAttributesInRect.frame.size.height);
    }
    return allAttributesInRect;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)itemIndexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:itemIndexPath];

    return layoutAttributes;
}

- (void)invalidateLayout
{

}
```

The BOOL

```
_collapse
```

is set is called in my collection view to trigger the animation. I am hoping to have the old cells, move from left to right, outside the view, and the new cells animate in from the right side of the screen. Right now, the cells are just moving off screen.

My issue is that the code in layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath and layoutAttributesForElementsInRect are not animating correctly. Would adding the animation code in these methods be the best place to perform the animations, or im totally off?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do anything to the result of

```
[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

nor

```
[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
```

If you want your cells to animate from where they are to off the screen, then you need to modify only their "final" position by overriding `finalAttributesForDisappearingElementAtIndexPath:`, but not their "regular position".

If you want them to come back from the side of the screen then you need to modify their position through `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:`